# creating nuget: can not package referenced dlls

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget, nuget-package

Im trying to create a nuget using the "Nuget Package Explorer". The project references 2 dlls witch target .net4.0 and the main dll targets .net4.5.

As specified, i put the 2 referenced dlls in a folder inside the "lib" folder called "net40", the main dll in a folder called "net45", then i pushed the nuget wich is located [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Osmos.TextTemplating/0.0.12-alpha/)

But when i try to install it in another project, it doesnt take any of the dlls !

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

The nuget package contains:

```
lib (folder)
    net45 (folder)
        MainAssembly.dll -> targets .net_4.5
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0 -> targets .net_4
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0 -> targets .net_4
```

notes:

- `MainAssembly` needs the two other assemblies
- I just want to target the .net version 4.5

the problem :

creating a nuget package using the structure above doesnt work, when intalling the nuget in a new project the `MainAssembly` is not added the list of references, only the two other assemblies are added.

Answer (score 0):

> The project references 2 dlls witch target .net4.0 and the main dll targets .net4.5.
>
> As specified, i put the 2 referenced dlls in a folder inside the "lib" folder called "net40", the main dll in a folder called "net45", then i pushed the nuget wich is located [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Osmos.TextTemplating/0.0.12-alpha/)

A NuGet package can target multiple .NET framework versions. However, a .NET project cannot.

Your dependent assemblies must be placed in the same .NET framework version folder in order for them to install into the target project. So, if you want your NuGet package to target 4.0 and 4.5, the structure should look like:

```
lib
    net40
        MainAssembly.dll
        DependentAssembly1.dll
        DependentAssembly2.dll
    net45
        MainAssembly.dll
        DependentAssembly1.dll
        DependentAssembly2.dll
```

The main assembly in each group must target the same framework version as the parent folder. The dependent assemblies can target any version the same or lower than the target version.

Note that typically each assembly is packaged as a separate NuGet package and the NuGet packages depend on each other, rather than putting the dependent assembiles into the same package.

Comment: thanks, i get your point. but
now when i put all the dlls in the v45 folder, it doenst work either, nuget will only grab the dependent assemblies not the main one.

Comment: note that in my case: mainassembly.dll targets 4.5, and the two depent assemblies target 4.0. putting them all in the same 4.5 doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your main assembly must target v4.0 (or lower) in order to be placed into the `net40` folder, or it won't be able to install into a v4.0 target project. In the `net45` folder it can target v4.5. See [this post](http://shazwazza.com/post/multi-targeting-a-single-net-project-to-build-for-different-framework-versions/) about setting up your project to build for multiple .NET framework versions. Note that your question is not clear what .NET framework version your target project (the project you will install this NuGet Package into) is using, which is where those folders come into play.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, i added an update to the question.